# ML Engine batch prediction job error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm encountering a frustrating error when submitting a batch prediction job to GCP ML Engine. The job successfully queues but fails with:

```
Forbidden: 403 The caller does not have permission (POST https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:write) [while running 'BATCH_PREDICTION/Prediction/ParDo(PredictionDoFn)/Do']
```

I've successfully trained my model and deployed it all via 'gcloud ml-engine' calls. I can also successfully make an online prediction submission via 'gcloud ml-engine predict'.

I prepared my batch prediction job as instructed [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/batch-predict).

```
DATA_FORMAT="TEXT"
INPUT_PATHS='gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[INUPT_DIR]/-*'
OUTPUT_PATH='gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OUTPUT_DIR]' 
MODEL_NAME='[MODEL_NAME]'
VERSION_NAME='v1'
REGION='europe-west1'
now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
JOB_NAME="predict_$now"
MAX_WORKER_COUNT="20"

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction $JOB_NAME \
--model $MODEL_NAME \
--input-paths $INPUT_PATHS \
--output-path $OUTPUT_PATH \
--region $REGION \
--data-format $DATA_FORMAT \
--verbosity debug
```

I also found a [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1614#issuecomment-197391860) describing a similar problem that recommends including the cloud-logs@google.com group with the owner role in the bucket's ACL. I updated the ACL. When I run

```
gsutil acl get gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

I see the following as one of the entries.

```
{
    "email": "cloud-logs@google.com",
    "entity": "group-cloud-logs@google.com",
    "role": "OWNER"
}
```

However, I still get the 403 error. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a request being sent to Cloud Logging is being rejected because the account executing the request doesn't have access.

This could be a few things:

1. You've requested "debug" level verbosity (`--verbosity debug`) when running the prediction job. Try removing that and see if it works?
2. You don't have the Stackdriver Logging API enabled. Try turning that on in the [API manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/logging.googleapis.com/overview)
3. The service account acting on your behalf (I think that's `cloud-logs@google.com`) doesn't have access to make requests to your project via the Strackdriver logging API. Try adding that specific account e-mail via the [IAM console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project)

   [image: Adding cloud-logs@google.com to Logging API]

Comment: I tried all three steps with no luck. Looking closely at the error message, the problem may not concern GCS. It looks like a DataFlow issue since the batch prediction is running as a "ParDo". Is it possible the DataFlow process is the "caller" and needs some explicit permission to post log messages?

Comment: If JJ's suggestion didn't work for you, do you mind share your project_id and job_id for the failed request so we can take a closer took? You may post them on cloudml-feedback@google.com.